# Colorscheme in .vimrc not working

Tags: vim

I've looked through a bunch of questions here, and I'm pretty experienced with Vim, but for some reason my `.vimrc` isn't setting the `colorscheme` any more.

I don't know when this started, but I just moved to a new machine and it's rather baffling to me. The oddest part is I'm able to set it manually `:colorscheme vividchalk`, it just won't work when I have `colorscheme vividchalk` in `.vimrc`. I tried commenting out absolutely everything else in my `.vimrc`, still no luck. Tried commenting out everything but `syntax on` and `set t_Co=256`, still no luck (and same behavior of manual settings working).

Any ideas? My setup is `ssh`-ing into my Ubuntu computer from Chrome OS.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Answer completely revised for others.]

Since the "`:colorscheme`" command works manually it proves you have the colorscheme installed.  This means you somehow have something coming after it in your initialization scripts that is overriding your preferred scheme.  You can track this down by typing "`:scriptnames`" and reading through it for another colorscheme being loaded.  Once you find it, you can remove or comment out that line in whatever initialization script it is being called from.

Comment: No, unfortunately it's listed there. I have `vividchalk.vim` in my `~/.vim/colors` directory, and as I mentioned it loads perfectly fine as long as I type `:colorscheme vividchalk` in a vim session. It's just like something else overrides it, but nothing else is loaded.

Comment: And here I thought I had correctly read your question. I apologize.  What does the output of "`:scriptnames`" show?

Comment: No worries; thanks for taking the time to reply at all!
Ah yes, and I think this is where the problem lies...so it has a bunchhh of things in there, but it's too long for this comment so I'll post it separately.

On top of that, before I commented out some color thing in the `synload.vim` (from line 4 above), it had some error about not being able to find a colorscheme called "ansi_blows" when running `:so $MYVIMRC`. Any ideas which file I should investigate further?

Comment: 1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc                                                                                                                                                                                      
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  6: ~/.vimrc
  7: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 10: ~/.vim/colors/vividchalk.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim

Comment: 12: ~/.vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim
 13: ~/.vim/plugin/scheme_00.vim
 14: ~/.vim/plugin/snipMate.vim
 15: ~/.vim/plugin/supertab.vim
 16: ~/.vim/plugin/tmux_navigator.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim

Comment: 23: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 27: ~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
 28: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/vim.vim
 29: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim

Comment: YAYYYY!!!! It was that bloody `scheme_00.vim`......thanks!

Comment: Fantastic. You just hit the bull's eye right away. Thank you Heptite

Comment: @Heptite There are a lot of things that are run before and after my `~/.vimrc` it seems. Is there a way to just instruct that my `~/.vimrc` is run last, so that that it'll overwrite whatever has happened before that?

Comment: In my case, my mistake was putting `colorscheme ...` _before_ `set t_Co=256` and causing the problem.

Answer (score 18):

`set background=dark` should be before `syntax enable` and `colorscheme whatever` in your .vimrc

Comment: vim visual select mode kills easy use. 
Solution is  set mouse-=a into your ~/. vimrc file but after that syntax coloring was gone. Both are necessary to turn back to the good old vim.

Answer (score 9):

For others like me stumbling in:

If you are using `vim` or `nvim` inside a terminal emulator, make sure that the colors settings for your profile are right. For `gnome-terminal`, I had to disable "use colors from system theme" in my Preferences/Profile/Color settings before I could get my colorscheme to properly work:

[image]

Also, as of recently nvim has deprecated `NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR` in favor of `set termguicolors` (see [this](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Following-HEAD#20160511)).

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem on Debian stretch, also with some other commands (color and set background work manually but not in .vimrc). But I didn't want to look through every file in scriptnames.

Solution is to add

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

to .vimrc

This line can be found in /usr/share/vim/vimXX/vimrc_example.vim for reference (XX is vim version, in my case 80).

I suppose defaults.vim does some configuration stuff necessary for changing the color. But defaults.vim is not loaded if the user has a ~/.vimrc, according to  /usr/share/vim/vimrc

```
" Vim will load $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim if the user does not have a vimrc.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use color schemes from plugins (external repositories). So I have to load plugins before applying `colorscheme` command.

Answer (score 1):

## .gvimrc

When using `gvim`, it may be necessary to put `colorscheme vividchalk` also in the `.gvimrc` file, despite this already being present in `.vimrc`

`:scriptnames` may reveal when a default colorscheme like `/usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/ron.vim` is being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just duplicated an existing theme, delek.vim, and renamed it to mydelek.vim and changed a few colors. However, `colorscheme mydelek` in  .vimrc would still load delek.vim.

Then I figured out I also need to change this line inside mydelek.vim:

```
let g:colors_name = "delek"
```

to:

```
let g:colors_name = "mydelek"
```

After that mydelek was properly loaded instead of delek. Hope this helps somebody who is also just tweaking an existing theme.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and my problem was putting the

```
   call plug#end()
```

at the end of the .vimrc file instead of right after the plugin list. Posting it here, so it may help someone finding this thread via search engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with your system first you need to check the `Use colour from system`

For that go to Preferences and Colors section you will get this option (by default it is uncheck in some system)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
" Vim will load $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim if the user does not have a vimrc.
" This happens after /etc/vim/vimrc(.local) are loaded, so it will override
" any settings in these files.
" If you don't want that to happen, uncomment the below line to prevent
" defaults.vim from being loaded.
```

let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1

Answer (score 0):

I need to reload `~/.vimrc` everytime I open the vim so that the colorscheme would work.

Add this remap into `.vimrc`:

`nnoremap <leader>v :source ~/.vimrc<CR>`

Comment: Using [Neovim](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim) is also a solution.