# vim colorscheme issue on redhat

Tags: linux, ssh, vim, colors, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have set my colorscheme to desert in my redhat 6 .vimrc. In redhat 6, when I open vi any file, it is displayed using the colorscheme.

There is a redhat 8 machine that I can ssh to and when I do, my user profile from the redhat 6 environment is carried across. I can see the same colorscheme setting in my .vimrc on the redhat 8 machine as well.

However, when I vi a file, it is not displayed using the colorscheme desert, but some other colorscheme which is not easy on my eyes.

I searched this forum for possible solutions and came across [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/682564/colorscheme-in-vimrc-not-working). I tried following the instructions in the accepted solution without avail, as I could not locate another script wherein colorscheme has been set to anything other than desert.

What should I do to get rid of this discrepancy on redhat 8, so that the colorscheme is set according to my .vimrc, as in the case of redhat 6?

TIA

Comment: I would like to add that in redhat 6 my vim is aliased to gvim whereas on redhat 8 it is not.

Comment: How do you know it is not `desert`? What does `:colorscheme` say in both cases? Also, the redhat versions don't really matter. Please add the **full** output of `$ vim --version` on both machines to your answer.